# Error when running the Spring Boot testing codes in a JMPS modular application

Tags: java, junit, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I am trying to create a modular Spring Boot sample using JMPS which introduced in Java 9.

Currently, I created a standalone Maven module for the testing work.

```java
module greeting.webapp.test {
    requires greeting.webapp;
    requires spring.test;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.web;
    requires spring.boot.starter.webflux;
    requires spring.boot.starter.test;
    requires spring.boot.test;
    requires spring.boot.test.autoconfigure;
    requires org.junit.jupiter;
    requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
    requires org.junit.jupiter.params;
    requires org.junit.jupiter.engine;
    requires org.junit.platform.commons;
    requires org.assertj.core;
    requires mockito.junit.jupiter;
}
```

And when run the [sample test](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/tree/master/modular-jmps/greeting-webapp-test/src/main/java/com/example/greeting), I got the following errors.

```sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.junit.platform.launcher.TestIdentifier (in unnamed module @0x6325a3ee) cannot access class org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions (in module org.junit.platform.commons) because module org.junit.platform.commons does not export org.junit.platform.commons.util to unnamed module @0x6325a3ee
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.TestIdentifier.from(TestIdentifier.java:56)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.<clinit>(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:86)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:377)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.getAgentClass(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:210)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

And in the test module, I have to move the test scoped deps to compile time to make it work in jmps, how to resolve this issue?

Comment: it would be great if you could provide some feedback about the answer...

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way, or no good way at all, imho.

The problem you are having is that you have not configured [maven surefire correctly](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/jpms.html). You can try that - I did and somehow was unlucky, but I did not invest too much time in making it work (neither do I think that will work, but that is a different problem). Instead I configured surefire plugin manually, via:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    --add-exports org.junit.platform.commons/org.junit.platform.commons.util=ALL-UNNAMED
                    --add-exports org.junit.platform.commons/org.junit.platform.commons.logging=ALL-UNNAMED
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Overall, I like `gradle` approach more. You can read on my experience with it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46613214/java-9-maven-junit-does-test-code-need-module-info-java-of-its-own-and-wher/63386799#63386799). I also don't think that IDEs (`Intellij` in my case) have yet proper support to run a single (maven based project) test, unlike gradle. But, to be fair, I only tried that against your repo, so far...

You can also read about a rather neat approach that gradle has taken when you need to declare modules [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204044/gradle-jigsaw-module-not-found/63457166#63457166), with their dedicated plugin.

Comment: This could be a fallback way for those jars not ready for java modules, JUnit itself is jmps modularized, I still encoutered other issues there, I will update you when I focus on it later.