# Dependening on legacy jar in Java 9 Module System library using gradle

Tags: java, gradle, java-9, java-platform-module-system, unnamed-module

### Problem

How do you create a java library jar that both:

- is java module (has `module-info`)
- has a depending legacy (non-module) jar. (like `commons-exec`)?

The dependency is an implementation detail - should not be exported.

### Sources

Having the following `build.gradle` (using `gradle-6.8`):

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

group = 'test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '15'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
java {
    modularity.inferModulePath = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-exec:1.3'
}
```

and the following `module-info.java`:

```
module test.module {
    requires commons.exec;
}
```

### Errors

I'm getting the following compile error:

```
module-info.java:2: error: module not found: commons.exec
    requires commons.exec;
                    ^
```

If I don't include `requires commons.exec` then the error becomes:

```
error: package org.apache.commons.exec is not visible
import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
                         ^
  (package org.apache.commons.exec is declared in the unnamed module,
   but module test.module does not read it)
```

### `commons.exec` module name?

Running `jar --file=commons-exec-1.3.jar --describe-module`  does output:

```
No module descriptor found. Derived automatic module.

commons.exec@1.3 automatic
requires java.base mandated
contains org.apache.commons.exec
contains org.apache.commons.exec.environment
contains org.apache.commons.exec.launcher
contains org.apache.commons.exec.util
```

So `commons.exec` looks like a valid module name for `commons-exec-1.3.jar`. Intelij Idea seem to agree and does auto-complete it in `module-info.java`. Though it fails at build time.

Comment: [related, if not exactly the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204044/gradle-jigsaw-module-not-found/63457166#63457166)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to overcome the same issue using [java-module-info](https://github.com/jjohannes/extra-java-module-info) plugin.

> This plugin allows you to add module information to a Java library
> that does not have any. If you do that, you can give it a proper
> module name and Gradle can pick it up to put it on the module path
> during compilation, testing and execution.

```
plugins {
   id 'java-library'
   id("de.jjohannes.extra-java-module-info") version "0.6"
}
```

Add this section into your `build.gradle` to add the **commons-exec** module information

```
  extraJavaModuleInfo {
    module("commons-exec-1.3.jar", "org.apache.commons.exec", "1.3") {
        exports("org.apache.commons.exec")
    }
}
```

Add `requires org.apache.commons.exec;` to your `module-info.java`

**EDIT 1**:

*Gradle 7.0* comes with full support for the *Java* module system. Users can now [build, test, and run](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_modular) *Java* modules via *Gradle*. The mere presence of `module-info.java` will let *Gradle* infer that your jar is a module and has to be put on the modulepath instead of the traditional classpath.

[Using libraries that are not modules](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#using_libraries_that_are_not_modules)